# What takes priority in StructureMap - For<T> or AddRegistry<T>?

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap

I've got this type that's injected with an `IFoo`:

```
class MainThing
{
    public MainThing(IFoo foo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Name);
    }
}
```

... and this interface:

```
interface IFoo
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

... and these two implementations of `IFoo`:

```
class Foo1 : IFoo
{
    public string Name { get { return @"Foo1"; } }
}

class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    public string Name { get { return @"Foo2"; } }
}
```

... and I've got this StructureMap registration:

```
        var c = new Container(e =>
        {
            e.AddRegistry<Registry1>();
            e.AddRegistry<Registry2>();
            e.For<IFoo>().Use<Foo1>();
        });

class Registry1 : Registry
{
    public Registry1() { For<IFoo>().Use<Foo1>(); }
}

class Registry2 : Registry
{
    public Registry2() { For<IFoo>().Use<Foo2>(); }
}
```

When I called `c.GetInstance<MainThing>();`, I was expecting `MainThing` to be given a `Foo1` instance, **but it's given a `Foo2` instance**.

The documentation says that subsequent `AddRegistry` calls overwrite the default instances declared in prior registries.  I assumed that because I appended a `.Use<Foo1>` at the end, that it'd trump everything else before it, but it's not.

Here's `WhatDoIHave()`:

```
===========================================================================================================
Configuration Sources:

0)   Registry:  StructureMap.ConfigurationExpression, StructureMap, Version=2.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e60ad81abae3c223
1)   Registry:  ConsoleApplication13.Registry1, ConsoleApplication13, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
2)   Registry:  ConsoleApplication13.Registry2, ConsoleApplication13, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
3)   Registry:  StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Registry, StructureMap, Version=2.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e60ad81abae3c223


===============================================================================================================================================================================================================
PluginType                               Name                                     Description                                                                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Func`1<TResult> (Func`1<TResult>)                                                                                                                                                                              
Scoped as:  Transient

                                         478e77e8-ff84-47e2-bdc1-b90bac2e7b61                                                                                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IFoo (ConsoleApplication13.IFoo)         f10f7750-f009-4842-ae35-7af47826ac2b     Configured Instance of ConsoleApplication13.Foo2, ConsoleApplication13, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Scoped as:  Transient

                                         9bd57a90-9c1e-4674-b249-7e6e96b40945     Configured Instance of ConsoleApplication13.Foo1, ConsoleApplication13, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
                                         3e14df0c-da47-40e2-96ed-9bc6027a5da8     Configured Instance of ConsoleApplication13.Foo1, ConsoleApplication13, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
                                         f10f7750-f009-4842-ae35-7af47826ac2b     Configured Instance of ConsoleApplication13.Foo2, ConsoleApplication13, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IContainer (StructureMap.IContainer)     cb17947d-5814-4c9b-a219-f359333d6fdb     Object:  StructureMap.Container                                                                                              
Scoped as:  Transient

                                         cb17947d-5814-4c9b-a219-f359333d6fdb     Object:  StructureMap.Container                                                                                              
===============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Foo2
```

I can see there's 3 instances of `IFoo` and that `Foo2` is the default, but I don't know why.

Does StructureMap give `AddRegistry` priority over `For`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this is correct:

When I instantiate a `new Container( e=> ... )`, I get the **default** registry.

I then add two registries, of which both overwrite any configuration if the default registry.

I then change something in the **default registry**, but this has already been overwritten when adding `Registry2`.